# Is there a lua equivalent of the javascript encodeURI() function?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am currently using openresty nginx to proxy requests to an origin. I want to escape any unsafe characters in the uri of the request.
Basically, I am looking for a lua equivalent for the `encodeURI()` javascript function.

Is there a method in Lua, similar to encodeURI() in JS?

I have looked at `ngx.escape_uri`, but this function only escapes a URI component.

I want the uri `/test/[hello]` to become `/test/%5Bhello%5D` after encoding the URI.
If I do `encodeURI("/test/[hello]/");` in JS, I get the desired output which is `/test/%5Bhello%5D`.

But, in Lua, if I do `ngx.escape_uri("/test/[hello]/")`, I get the output as '%2Ftest%2F%5Bhello%5D'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngx.escape_uri` has an option to escape a full URI:

> syntax: newstr = ngx.escape_uri(str, type?)

> Since v0.10.16, this function accepts an optional type argument. It accepts the following values (defaults to 2):
>
> **0: escapes str as a full URI.** [...]
>
> 2: escape str as a URI component. [...]

Nonetheless, `ngx.escape_uri(str, 0)` is still not the same as `encodeURI`.

Fortunately, it's easy to write your own function that produce exactly the same output as `encodeURI`:

```lua
local function _encode_uri_char(char)
    return string.format('%%%0X', string.byte(char))
end

local function encode_uri(uri)
    return (string.gsub(uri, "[^%a%d%-_%.!~%*'%(%);/%?:@&=%+%$,#]", _encode_uri_char))
end
```

```lua
-- prints /test/%5Bhello%5D/
ngx.say(encode_uri('/test/[hello]/'))
```

The `encode_uri` function escapes all characters except:

```
A–Z a–z 0–9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

; / ? : @ & = + $ , #
```

as it described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

Comment: This `encode_uri` implementation in Lua helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155208/ngx-escape-uri-didnt-work-on) helps you

Also, a quick solution would be to replace "%2F" to "/".

```
newUrl = oldUrl:gsub("%2F", "/")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Since, the following characters `; / ? : @ & = + $ , #` are characters that may be part of the URI syntax, so I am looking for a way in which these should not be escaped.